# How do I properly fit a sci-kit learn model using a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to create a machine learning program in sci-kit learn. I am using a CSV file to store data, and have decided to use Pandas data frame to import and format this data. I cannot figure out how to fit this data frame with the model.

My CSV file has one feature, age, and one target, weight. I am using a linear regression algorithm to predict the weight using the age. I do realize this isn't the best algorithm to use with this data.

When I run this code I get the error "ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [10, 40]"

Here is my code:

```
# Imports 
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Load And Split Data
data = pd.read_csv("awd.csv")

feature_cols = ['Ages']
X = data.loc[:, feature_cols]
y = data.loc[:, "Weights"]

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, train_size=0.2)

# Train Model
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Scores
print(f"Test set score: {round(lr.score(X_test, y_test), 3)}")
print(f"Training set score: {round(lr.score(X_train, y_train), 3)}")
```

The first 5 lines of my CSV file:

```
Ages,Weights
1,19
1,21
2,26
2,32
```

Comment: Can you please share the full error trace, some sample data, and the shapes of X and y?

Comment: Are you going to leave us guessing?  Where's the error?  What variables have 10 and 40 samples?  You need to put some effort into debugging the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the super late response. I will make sure to include as much information as I can on my next question. I have fixed the problem with the answers from the question. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning the return values incorrectly. See below:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0, train_size=0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should correct the order of X_train, X_test, y_train and y_test like this:

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
```

See the relevant [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) for details.